# Makefile printing messages without compiling every time

Tags: compilation, makefile, linker, echo

I have a makefile that compiles and links several c++ projects, and in general I would like it to print a message for every project it compiles/links - but only when it has to do something for that target. I have something like this:

```
Project_1: print_1 main_1.o $(Objects_1)
    ${CXX} main_1.o $(Objects_1) -o $@ ${CXXLDFLAGS} 

print_1:
    @echo "Project 1"

$(DIR_BLD_CXX)/main_1.o: $(DIR_SRC_CXX)/main_1.cpp $(Hfiles_1)
    ${CXX} -c $(DIR_SRC_CXX)/main_1.cpp ${MYCXXFLAGS} -o $@
```

And this works; however everywhere I use a phony target (?) to print something it will compile/link every time, regardless if something relevant has been changed.

Is there a way to print a message at certain targets, but only whenever something has changed that means the target has to be compiled?

Comment: You want it to print a message for some targets even when make doesn't have (or do) anything for those targets?

Comment: No sorry if it's unclear: that's exactly what I want to avoid; I would like it to print the messages but only when it has to do something for the target. Oh and actually it compiles/links every time there is a message as well, I think I'll have to edit the question

Comment: Stick the echo in the recipe with the commands to run and it'll only run/print when the target recipe runs.

Comment: The reason your targets run every time is because `print_1` isn't a real file and is always "new". You are *causing* the problem you are trying to fix by being more clever than you should be. Just put both the `echo` and `${CXX}` commands in the recipe for `Project_1` and be done.

Comment: Ah thanks, that works! However ideally I'd like it to print a message for every project (so before compiling object files and linking), but if I stick the echo with a compile command it will only print with that one (or with all of them if I stick it with all and they all change) and if I stick it with the linking command it will come after the compilations.. Do I have to use some sort of conditionals etc?

Comment: Targets are run starting with the first dependency that can be built directly. The "project"/toplevel target is the last thing to build. To get a message printed *before* any of the dependencies are run you would need to force a custom "bottom" dependency on all the parts of your projects. That may or may not be an easy or reasonable thing to do. You could look at something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24894487/258523) which does recipe output prefixing as that might get something close enough to what you want.

Comment: ***Why*** do you want it to print all of the messages before any compiling and linking?

Comment: When something in a given project (as in some object files linked together) has changed I would like to print a single message about that project before compiling/linking as necessary according to changes in the project. For now I've abandoned this though, electing to have no messages.