# Using implicit rules while displaying custom messages

Tags: makefile

Lets suppose I want the benefits provided by implicit rules while also showing a progress message in the form of:

```
Compiling [main.cpp]
(...)
Linking...
```

Writing the `%.o: %.cpp` rule with the message replaces the implicit rule.
And writing the whole rule explicitly defeats the goal of using implicit rules.
So, any suggestions?

PS: If this isn't currently possible with make, it's ok.
PPS: **NO CMAKE**
PPPS: **NO [AUTOFOOLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714100/os-detecting-makefile#comment14369018_743444)**

Comment: Is the answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24820594/258523) close enough to what you want? You might be able tweak it to only output the message once with some clever use of `$(eval)` if necessary.

Comment: @EtanReisner Close, but it gave me an idea on how to do it.

Comment: You can prepend things to `COMPILE.cpp` to do part of what you want but getting `$@` in there correctly was escaping me in some quick attempts. I'm curious to see what you come up with.

Comment: @EtanReisner Posted it as answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$(CXX)` is used to compile C++ sources and `$(CC)` is used to link the objects together, I can prepend an `echo` to both.

```
CC = @echo "Linking..."; g++
CXX = @echo "Compiling [$<]"; g++
```

This will output the desired results.

Comment: `$(CC)` is used in other places though so this won't always work correctly.

Comment: @EtanReisner I know, it's used to compile C files as well, but I'm only working with C++ at this point, so it fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    @echo compiling $<
    $(CC) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEFS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: "And writing the whole rule explicitly defeats the goal of using implicit rules."
You didn't read my question properly.

Comment: oh, sorry..yeah, you need a workaround like a bash file, maybe.